# Tabstrip in FireFox renders differently on Mac & Ubuntu vs PC

Tags: css, firefox, platform-specific

I have this simple css tabstrip that renders as expected in:

- Safari 5.0.2 on Mac
- IE8 on PC
- FireFox 3.8.12 on PC

However, in FireFox 3.8.12 on Mac and Ubuntu the tabs overlap the bottom border of the container div by 1 pixel. I'm no css expert and haven't figured out how to get this (or a better solution) to render the same in FireFox on all platforms.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial;
}

#tabstrip {
 width:700px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #6a8fa7;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: block;
 height: 21px;
 margin: 0;
 padding:  0 0 0px 0;
}

#tabstrip ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1px 0 0 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#tabstrip li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}

#tabstrip a {
 color: #999999;
 padding: 5px 8px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 background-color: #d7d7d7;
 margin: 0 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#tabstrip a:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}

#tabstrip a.selected {
 background-color: #6a8fa7;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #666;
}

#tabstrip a.done {
 background-color: #60b43f;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #666;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<br/><br/>

<div id="tabstrip">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/" class="done">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/" class="selected">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Item 5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to fix the same issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csstype="inline" //Specify type of CSS to use. "Inline" or "external"
    var mac_css='#nav li a {line-height: 46px; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 13px;}' //if "inline", specify mac css here
    var pc_css='#nav li a {line-height: 43px; padding-top: 13px; padding-bottom: 11px;}' //if "inline", specify PC/default css here
    var mac_externalcss='/style/macstyle.css' //if "external", specify Mac css file here
    var pc_externalcss='/style/pcstyle.css'   //if "external", specify PC/default css file here
    ///////No need to edit beyond here////////////
    var mactest=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")!=-1
    if (csstype=="inline"){
        document.write('<style type="text/css">')
        if (mactest)
        document.write(mac_css)
        else
        document.write(pc_css)
        document.write('</style>')
        }
        else if (csstype=="external")
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+ (mactest? mac_externalcss : pc_externalcss) +'">')
        </script>
```